# How to Show or Hide a div using useState in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I’m new to React but trying to build a responsive website with a “desktop header” and “mobile header” that is shown when the user clicks on a menu-icon-toggle and closes when the user clicks on Close-icon.
I’m obviously doing it wrong but can’t seem to figure out what the problem is, I believe that NextJS doesn’t know what to open or close.

**Note: I´m using TailwindCSS and this is a component that will be rendered on the index page

My code looks something like this (simplified, without all the content):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/Image'

function header() {

const \[mobile__Header, setMobile__Header\] = useState(false)

const showMobile__Header = () =\> setMobile__Header(!mobile__Header)

return (\<div\>

        {/* mobile header */}
    
        <div className='absolute flex flex-col w-screen h-screen place-content-between bg-white text-black p-5 z-50'>
    
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
    
                {/* Left Logo */}
    
                <div className='cursor-pointer'>
                    
                </div>
    
                {/* close icon */}
    
                <div className='cursor-pointer' onClick={showMobile__Header}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            {/* nav links */}
    
            <div className='flex'>
                <div className='flex flex-col text-xl space-y-3'>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    
            {/* Social links and languaje changer */}
    
            <div className='flex justify-between font-light'>
                <div>
                    <a className="link" href="">EN</a>
                </div>
    
                <div className='flex flex-col'>
                   
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
        {/* desktop header */}
    
        <header className="flex w- px-10 py-1 justify-between">
                
    
             <div className="flex">
    
                {/* Left Logos */}
    
                <div className="flex md:hidden cursor-pointer">
                    
                </div>
    
                <div className="hidden md:flex cursor-pointer">
                    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            
            <div className="flex items-center">
    
                {/* Menu icon toggle */}
    
                <div className='flex md:hidden cursor-pointer' onClick={showMobile__Header}>
    
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                    </svg>
    
                </div>
    
                {/* Right Nav Links and language changer */}
    
                <div className="space-x-4 px-5 py-5 hidden md:flex ">
                    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            
    
        </header>
    
    
    
        
    </div>
    )}
    export default header
```

Comment: Question - why would you need to toggle between the desktop and the mobile view?  Why not just use CSS breakpoints, create two components called ````mobileNav```` and ````desktopNav```` and make sure the ````div```` that wraps the ````desktopNav```` is on ````display: none```` until a certain resolution is hit.  EDIT:  I would have no problem implementing what you want but I was just curious as to why this approach.  Are you trying to show a mobile view, even outside of a standard mobile resolutions?

Comment: @AttemptedMastery I should have probably explained this better, I have a normal header that when the viewport size decreases it hides the nav links and displays a hamburger menu. After that menu is clicked I wanted to display the mobileNav component (which covers the viewport, shows all nav links, social links, etc and has a close icon inside) similar to a sidebar or something like that. I tried initially having two components but couldn´t find a way to open and close the component when the icon is in the other one (hamburger-menu and close-icon)

Comment: @SeanW Okay, thanks. I will check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have many HTML/CSS issues like positioning and element structure.

The [free tailwindui example](https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/elements/headers) is a solid example to reference.  It has nice transitions and accessibility baked in, which I removed for the example.  It also uses [headlessui](https://headlessui.dev/) and [heroicons](https://heroicons.com/), both were built by the TW team. The TW menu components handle the state internally, so you will not be able to see the logic in their example.

The below responsive example is based on the above-referenced version but without external dependencies.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => setOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
      <header className="relative bg-white">
        <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6">
          <div className="flex justify-between items-center border-b-2 border-gray-100 py-6 md:justify-start md:space-x-10">
            <div className="flex justify-start lg:w-0 lg:flex-1">
              <a href="#">
                <span className="h-8 w-auto sm:h-10">LOGO</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div className="-mr-2 -my-2 md:hidden">
              <button
                onClick={toggleMenu}
                className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
              >
                Open
              </button>
            </div>
            <nav className="hidden md:flex space-x-10">
              <a href="#" className="text-base font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">
                About
              </a>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        {isOpen && (
          <div className="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
            <div className="rounded-lg shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 bg-white divide-y-2 divide-gray-50">
              <div className="pt-5 pb-6 px-5">
                <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                  <div>
                    <span className="h-8 w-auto">LOGO</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="-mr-2">
                    <button
                      onClick={toggleMenu}
                      className="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500"
                    >
                      X
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-6">
                  <nav className="grid gap-y-8">
                    <a href="#" className="p-3 flex items-center rounded-md hover:bg-gray-50">
                      About
                    </a>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
  );
};
```

You will also likely need to handle the closing of the menu on route change.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => setOpen(!isOpen);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const closeMenu = () => isOpen && setOpen(false);
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", closeMenu);
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", closeMenu);
    };
  }, [isOpen, router]);

  return (
   ...see above example
```

Comment: Ah, I will have to save this for when I get to my router functionality.  Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what you are asking, this should set you down the right path, at least from a logic standpoint.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/Image'

function header() {

const [mobile__Header, setMobile__Header] = useState(false)

const showMobile__Header = (e) => {
    if (e.target.className.includes('mobile')) {
        setMobile__Header(true)
    } else if (e.target.className.includes('desktop')){
        setMobile__Header(false)
    }
}

return (
    <div>
        <div className='absolute flex flex-col w-screen h-screen place-content-between bg-white text-black p-5 z-50'>
    
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
    
    
                <div className='cursor-pointer'>
                    
                </div>
    
    
                <div className={mobile__Header === true ? 'cursor-pointer-mobile' : 'remove-display'} onClick={showMobile__Header}>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
    
            <div className='flex'>
                <div className='flex flex-col text-xl space-y-3'>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <div className='flex justify-between font-light'>
                <div>
                    <a className="link" href="">EN</a>
                </div>
    
                <div className='flex flex-col'>
                   
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
        
        <header className="flex w- px-10 py-1 justify-between">
                
    
             <div className="flex">
    
    
                <div className="flex md:hidden cursor-pointer">
                    
                </div>
    
                <div className="hidden md:flex cursor-pointer">
                    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            
            <div className="flex items-center">
    
    
                <div className={mobile__Header === false ? 'cursor-pointer-desktop' : 'remove-display'} onClick={showMobile__Header}>
    
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                    </svg>
    
                </div>
    
    
                <div className="space-x-4 px-5 py-5 hidden md:flex ">
                    
                </div>
    
            </div>
    
            
    
        </header>
     </div>
    )
}
    export default header
```

Basically, make sure to differentiate between your `mobile` button and your `desktop` button using your `classNames`.  Then, you set a `bolean` indicator depending on what is in the `className`.  From there, you either display the correct container, or use a `CSS class` that simply puts `display: none` (in this case, I used the name `remove-display`.  All that is done with an `inline ternary operator`.

Whether you are toggling a button, or toggling a whole container (a parent div that when `display: none` removes all the content inside), this approach works in both scenarios.

I am still confused as to what you are asking but my solution should get you going.  You have an `onClick` function on two divs and the comments above each of those says are misleading.  One says `close icon` and the other says `menu icon toggle`.  I am not sure what we are toggling.

EDIT: Here is a much cleaner way to do it and it involved no `className` toggling.  This will teach you what you are doing so you can actually toggle what you are trying to toggle:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function header() {

    const [isActivate, setActive] = useState(false)

    const handleActivate = (e) => {
        !isActivate ? setActivate(true) : setActivate(false)
}

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <h1 style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={handleActivate}>
                {isActivate === true ? 'OPEN' : false}
            </h1>
            <h1 style={{cursor: 'pointer'}} onClick={handleActivate}>
                {!isActivate ? 'CLOSE' : false}
            </h1>
        </div>
     </div>
    )
}
    export default header
```

Comment: The OPs original `showMobile__Header` is the preferred way to toggle the class in React.  You can toggle open/close and shouldn't rely on reading classes - the state is the source of truth, not the CSS class applied to the element.  Other parts of the application, libraries, browser extensions, etc., can modify the class, which could break the application.

Comment: You're right - I was flying by the seat of my pants writing that.  I'll show a refactored version later tonight.  Toggling classes still has a place in react but I obfuscated the problem.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery Thanks for the help, I´m trying to implement your suggestions now so let´s hope I can get it working.

Comment: @AttemptedMastery I understand the code you have provided but still don´t know how to make that work for me. So given your example, let´s say the h1 is a button (OPEN) and also has a paragraph below. Let there be another div with again, a button (CLOSE), and a paragraph below. The first button opens the second div and the second button closes itself. How would you structure that? I think with this answered I can get it to work. Thanks